# 'La/Le assicuro ...', 'La/Le rassicuro ...': quali sono le forme corrette?

Tags: verbs, pronouns

È più corretto dire '*Le assicuro che ...*' o '*La assicuro che ...*'?

Supponiamo che si voglia esprimere contrarietà allorché qualcuno, nell'ambito di relazioni non confidenziali, affermi erroneamente qualcosa, per esempio:

> *... tutte le ciambelle riescono col buco ...*

Come si dovrebbe rispondere?

a) *La assicuro che non è così, anzi*.

b) *Le assicuro che non è così, anzi*.

E se volessimo usare — ancorché forse meno propriamente — il verbo 'rassicurare'?

a.1) *La rassicuro che non è così, anzi*.

b.1) *Le rassicuro che non è così, anzi*.

Io preferisco b) e a.1), ma non capisco quale differenza fra 'assicurare' e 'rassicurare' incida al riguardo.

Comment: FYI, sono piuttosto sicuro che b1) sia sbagliata: il "le" significa "a lei", quindi la frase è equivalente a "Rassicuro a lei che...". Il verbo "rassicurare", a differenza di "assicurare", non regge la preposizione "a": perciò, "rassicuro a lei" è grammaticalmente sbagliato, e permissibile solo in forme dialettali tipiche del Sud Italia.

Answer (score 5):

"Assicurare" e "rassicurare" hanno due significati diversi.

- "Assicurare" significa (in questo caso) garantire con certezza che una certa cosa è vera, tipicamente a qualcuno che ne dubita.
- "Rassicurare" significa fare qualsiasi cosa (non necessariamente dicendo qualcosa) per portare qualcuno in uno stato di maggiore tranquillità rispetto ad un eventuale pericolo.

Non ho mai sentito l'uso di "assicurare" come "rassicurare", che suggerisce bobie. Mi sembra quanto meno una forma molto antiquata.

Naturalmente è possibile, assicurando qualcosa a qualcuno, che questo qualcuno ne risulti anche rassicurato. Non è per nulla necessario che, per rassicurare qualcuno, sia necessario assicurargli la verità di qualcosa (per esempio, in un contesto di paura e smarrimento una carezza o un sorriso possono avere un effetto rassicurante, senza peraltro assicurare nulla).

Nel merito delle frasi proposte, tra a) e b) è certamente da scegliere b), perché l'oggetto di "assicurare" è la verità che si intende asserire, mentre la persona a cui ci si rivolge va in dativo. Tra a.1) e b.1) è da preferire a.1), perché l'oggetto di "rassicurare" è la persona che viene rassicurata. In questo caso l'utilizzo della subordinata "che non è così" mi suona un po' strano, però non mi sembra sbagliato. Di sicuro sarebbe possibile dire "La rassicuro, non è così, anzi". In tal caso le due frasi sono semplicemente coordinate (e "rassicurare" può benissimo stare senza la subordinata, mentre invece "assicurare" dovrebbe comunque tenersi come complemento oggetto ciò che viene assicurato).

Comment: Mi viene da fare solo un appunto. Il verbo _rassicurare_ è, per così dire, un "verbo di conseguimento": tu puoi cercare di rassicurare qualcuno ma che quel qualcuno poi si senta effettivamente rassicurato è tutto un altro discorso. È strano rivolgersi a qualcuno dicendogli "_ti rassicuro_"; normalmente gli dirai "_vorrei rassicurarti che…_". Se poi pensi di averlo rassicurato potrai dire "_L'ho rassicurato che_". Inoltre va osservato che _rassicurare_ non è il verbo giusto per esprimere contrarietà, come richiede la domanda, a meno che non si voglia ricorrere allo sfottò.

Answer (score 2):

> *Le assicuro che non è così*

va bene: dici con certezza a qualcuno che non è così come questi crede; rendi certo qualcosa a qualcuno. Questa è la costruzione che tutti capiscono. Stai esprimendo all'interlocutore contrarietà: lo stai contraddicendo e glielo stai comunicando efficacemente, mostrandoti sicuro del fatto tuo.

> *La assicuro che non è così*

non ha molto senso, a meno che tu non stia cercando di ipnotizzare il tuo interlocutore. Potresti dire "*La vorrei assicurare che non è così*": non credo che questa scelta sia né comune né molto elegante ma la [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/assicurare/) ci assicura che si tratta di una scelta grammaticalmente corretta («*lo assicurai che suo figlio stava bene*»); ma comunemente si userebbe il verbo *rassicurare*. Come che sia: non stai contraddicendo l'interlocutore, lo stai rassicurando circa qualcosa di **sgradevole** che l'interlocutore **crede** o **teme**. Ma lui invece è **orgoglioso** che tutte le ciambelle escono col buco!

> *Gli assicurai che non era così*

va bene: hai assicurato a lui che non era così come credeva. L'hai contraddetto: esattamente quello che volevi fare.

> *Lo assicurai che non era così*

va anche bene (e si suppone che tu abbia qualche elemento per ritenere che il tuo interlocutore si sentisse poi effettivamente rassicurato). Rimane da capire come faccia a sentirsi rassicurata una persona che hai appena contraddetto circa qualcosa di cui è orgogliosamente convinta: si sentirà semmai più insicura, immagino, o persino irritata. Ma comunque sia, **non** stai contraddicendo l'interlocutore: la tua attenzione è focalizzata sulla sua serenità interiore.

> *La rassicuro che non è così*

suona male, a meno che non si intenda nel senso di "*La **voglio** rassicurare che non è così*". Ma anche così ha poco senso: vuoi rassicurare qualcuno che qualcosa che costui orgogliosamente ritiene vera sia invece falsa?! Come detto sopra sembra piuttosto che tu lo stia destabilizzando. Normalmente si rassicura qualcuno riguardo a qualcosa di **sgradevole** che questi **crede** o **teme**. Ad ogni modo: **non** lo stai contraddicendo, lo stai rassicurando.

> *Le rassicuro che non è così*

non va bene: non puoi rassicurare qualcosa a qualcuno. È errato.

> *Lo rassicurai che non era così*

va bene se pensi di averlo tranquillizzato. Ma sostenendo l'opinione opposta lo hai tranquillizzato? È cosa che devi valutare tu. Ma, come prima, **non** lo stai contraddicendo, ti stai concentrando sulla sua serenità interiore.

---

A parziale integrazione di quanto detto su, in italiano si può dire "*stai (pur) tranquillo che non è come dici tu*". Spesso questa costruzione viene accompagnata da note e toni di sarcasmo e aggressività: stai dicendo all'interlocutore "*stai tranquillo, non ti scomodare, rimani al tuo posto*" e intendi "*non infastidirmi*".

Comment: In generale è perfettamente ragionevole rassicurare qualcuno contraddicendolo, se ciò in merito al quale lo contraddici è qualcosa che egli dubita che sia vero o addirittura spera che non sia vero. Per esempio: «Lui mi disse: "Davvero domani vengono a distruggermi la casa?!". Lo rassicurai che non era così».

Comment: Quindi lo rassicuri riguardo a ciò che **teme**. In questo caso sono chiaramente d'accordo.