# Accenti circonflessi nella lingua italiana

Tags: orthography, accents

Leggendo questo [post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/2404/707) ho imparato che il plurale di *principio* si può scrivere *principî*. È stata una sorpresa per me scoprire l'esistenza di accenti circonflessi in italiano: non li avevo mai visti prima. Leggendo il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/assicurare/) a proposito di quest'altro [post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/2406/707), ho trovato un altro esempio di vocabolo con un accento circonflesso:

> Assicurare l’avvenire ai *proprî* figli.

Si tratta in questi due casi del plurale di parole finite in *-io*. Ci sono altri usi dell'accento circonflesso nella lingua italiana? L'uso di tale accento è piuttosto declinante?

Comment: Mi permetto di segnalare anche questa mia risposta a una domanda simile: http://italian.stackexchange.com/a/1336/189

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nell'italiano standard contemporaneo l'accento circonflesso è pressoché scomparso, usato in certi testi che tengono molto all'ortografia classica (come appunto il dizionario Treccani) e altrove al massimo per risolvere certe ambiguità, come il già citato principi/principî, assassini/assassinî (plurali di assassino e di assassinio), geni/genî (plurali di gene e di genio) e alcuni altri. Nella pratica, spesso anche questi si omettono e si usa la grafia alternativa in -ii, o semplicemente ci si affida al contesto.

In altri tempi l'accento circonflesso veniva usato in italiano anche per altre contrazioni, come “tôrre” per “togliere”, soprattutto in ambito poetico dove queste contrazioni erano utili a fini metrici.

Comment: A complemento della risposta, la differenza non è solo ortografica: in linea di principio *principi* e *principî* sono due parole con una pronuncia leggermente diversa. La "i" finale è, nel secondo caso, leggermente più lunga e semivocalica.

Comment: Cioè? Sembra tu stia dicendo che c'è pure una via di mezzo tra le pronunce i e ii. Che evidenza c'è che possa sostenere questo fatto? Sono curioso. Grazie.